# In my react application it gives error tha react and reactDOM is not defined

Tags: reactjs

i am starting to create a react app and it gives error that React and ReactDOM is not defined.I am adding my code here...`

```
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Indecision App</title>
       </head>

      <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
          <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
          <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"> 
          </script>
           <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>

         </body>

          </html>`
```

And my app.js file is this

```
       'var template = React.createElement("h1", {
        id: "id"
        }, "This is jsx from app.js");
       var appRoot = document.getElementById('app');

         ReactDOM.render(template,appRoot);`
```

Comment: replace your app.js code with https://stackoverflow.com/a/59676122/6544460

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined ReactDOM.

replace your code with this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
var template = React.createElement("h1", {
  id: "id"
  }, "This is jsx from app.js")
 var appRoot = document.getElementById('root');
 ReactDOM.render(template,appRoot);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
  var template = React.createElement(
    "h1",
    {
      id: "id"
    },
    "This is jsx from app.js"
  );
  var appRoot = document.getElementById("app");

  ReactDOM.render(template, appRoot);
})();
```

folder structure

[image]

Comment: You are welcome, please accept the answer as correct if this was useful